# Use INSERT-OUTPUT to provide values for another INSERT

Tags: sql, t-sql, insert

Good day,

I was wondering if it is possible to use an INSERT-OUTPUT statement in such a way as to provide the value(s) for another, outer, INSERT statement. That way values can be added to an entity table and an intersection table in a single statement - I hope I'm wording this effectively. For example:

```
INSERT INTO [#tblIntersect] ([Entity1ID], [Entity2ID])
VALUES
(
    INSERT INTO [#tblEntity1] ([Value])
    OUTPUT [inserted].[ID] AS [entity1ID], @entity2ID AS [entity2ID]
    VALUES ('One')
)
```

So the inner INSERT-OUTPUT statement will add a new entity to table `#tblEntity1`. The new entity's `ID` (which is set as `IDENTITY(1, 1)` will then be returned through the `OUTPUT` statement, along with a static value (which I already have in my code), to provide the two values for the outer `INSERT` statement.

The reason I think it might be possible is because execution of the inner `INSERT-OUTPUT` statement on its own returns a table anyway, and such output can usually be used to provide values for `INSERT` statements.

Obviously this example doesn't work; I was hoping it's just a simple syntax problem.

Thank you in advance for any comments and advice.

Comment: something like last-insert-id does not work in this case to fetch it again and use the select result of it for another insert?

Comment: it probably would, I was just trying to write the shortest query with the least separate statements :P

Comment: which database software is used?

Comment: added the tsql tag, if INSERT OUPUT is used.

Comment: i'm using sql 2008 and c# - it's a winforms application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement is possible according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Assuming #tblIntersect has two matching id columns this should work

```
INSERT INTO [#tblEntity1] ([Value])
OUTPUT [inserted].[ID] AS [entity1ID], @entity2ID AS [entity2ID]
   INTO #tblIntersect
VALUES ('One')
```